# regeneratorRuntime is not defined, Can I fix this with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, generator, babeljs

I use Gulp for transpiling ES6, but with generator it gives the error of: **"Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined".**

I have found that I need babel-polyfill for this and documentations suggests uses for  Node / Browserify / Webpack.

Can't I fix this in Gulp without webpack? I didn't find how. I installd babel-plugin-transform-regenerator and did this in my gulpfile.js:

```
    gulp.task('scripts', function() {
      return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
                 .pipe(plumber())
                 .pipe(babel({
                          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-3'],
                          plugins: ["transform-regenerator"]
                      }))
                 .pipe(uglify())
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/result'))
                 .pipe(browserSync.stream()); 

});
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This plugin still requires regeneratorRuntime. You need to install babel-polyfill and import it explicitly in your JS:

1. `npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill`
2. Copy polyfill to your static scripts folder:
   `cp node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js ./public/js`
3. Add polyfill script to the top of your html head
   `<script src="/public/js/polyfill.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, BUT. I actually tried both of these options. First one gives me in the terminal the following: " Using removed Babel 5 option: base.optional - Put the specific transforms you want in the `plugins` option". Maybe it needs some additional specific options, but I couldn't find which. And the second doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Just edited answer, sorry, runtime was moved to plugin.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. If you have any more ideas, I am glad to hear, but it didn't help. Now after this a new error appeared: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", I followed the error and found it here: var _regenerator=require("babel-runtime/regenerator")

Comment: I found out that there is no require in browser, so I am going to need something like browserify. I really hoped to do this without extra tools, though xD.

Comment: Right, or you will need to use gulp-requirejs plugin. I think easier is to get back to option 2, but instead of import you will need to add  at the top of your html:
`<script src="polyfill.min.js"></script>`

After installing babel-polyfill script is under node_modules, so copy it to your js static folder:
`cp node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js ./public/`

Comment: It worked for me with your gulp configuration, just edited answer

Comment: Great solution, I just needed this to get gulp to not blow up when running minify, simply adding this script to the `.src(['./public/js/polyfill.min.js', 'myOtherAsyncScriptsHere.js', ...])` worked like a charm